# How to check @ (at) in array, and remove this symbol after checking

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have an array with multiple entries. Some of these contain `@` at the beginning. That's an example of an array:

```
some string  
@another string  
@one more string  
the best string  
string with email@mail.com
```

For validation and grouping I use this part of code (it checked only `@` for now)

```
  if(linesArray[i] ===  '@'){
    $('#test').append('<li class="string_with_at">'+linesArray[i]+'</li>');
  }else{
    $('#test').append('<li class="string_no_at">'+linesArray[i]+'</li>');
  }
```

My questions are:

1. How can I check the `@` in line start for first group?
2. How can I remove this symbol from result ('li'+linesArray+'/li') - a may to leave only class to understand that it was an `@`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that:

```
if(linesArray[i][0] ===  '@') { //checking the first symbol
   //remove first element from result
   $('#test').append('<li class="string_with_at">'+linesArray[i].substring(1)+'</li>');
}
else {
   $('#test').append('<li class="string_no_at">'+linesArray[i]+'</li>');
}
```

Comment: it's better to use `.charAt(0)` instead of `[0]` for compatibility reasons

Comment: not a surprise that IE7 does not support it. thanks for your remark!

Answer (score 1):

Function to remove '@' if at position 0, and return newly formatted string:

```
removeAt = function(s){
    if(s.charAt(0) == '@')
      return s.substring(1);
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
function addElement (val) {
    var match = val.match(/^(@)(.*)/),
        at    = match[1],
        str   = match[2],
        li    = $('<li/>').html(str)

    li.addClass('string_' + (at ? 'with' : 'no') + '_at');

    $('#test').append(li);
}

linesArray.forEach(addElement);
```